# adv. styling list with css

Tags: css

I need to style a regular html list like the following picture:

[image]

as you see each each list item has a padding on the sides and a top&bottom border. When hovered the border has a width of 100% of the `<ul>` item. 
Now the problem actually is: when you give each `<li>` element a top & bottom border I have a border of 2 px between each element (bottom border from the first element and the top border from the second element), I don't want that however I do not know any solution for this.

my html:

```
<div id="tab_top" class="tab">
        <div class="bottom">
          <div class="cont">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Here’s a Sample Post <span class="ct">32</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Here’s a Sample Post <span class="ct">32</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Here’s a Sample Post <span class="ct">32</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Here’s a Sample Post <span class="ct">32</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Here’s a Sample Post <span class="ct">32</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Here’s a Sample Post <span class="ct">32</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Here’s a Sample Post <span class="ct">32</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

my css:

```
#tabs .tab div.cont ul li a{line-height:30px; height:30px; color:#3ca097; display:block; padding-left:11px; padding-right:13px; width:259px;}
#tabs .tab div.cont ul li a span.ct{float:right;background:url(images/count_comments.gif) no-repeat left top; height:13px; padding-left:16px; margin-top:10px; line-height:12px;}
#tabs .tab div.cont ul li a:hover{color:#fff; background-color:#6fd2c8; border-top:1px solid #7db9b2;  border-bottom:1px solid #7db9b2; height:28px; line-height:28px;}
#tabs .tab div.cont ul li a:hover span.ct{background-position:left bottom; color:#23665f; margin-top:9px;}
```

I would be pleased if you can help me

Yours truthfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use border-top and border-bottom, you are correct, you will get a 1px border, if however you use both, then specify li+li like so:

```
.tab div.cont ul li { border-top: 1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black; }
.tab div.cont ul li + li { border-top:none; }
```

You will get what you claim to want.

Comment: +1 For what it's worth, this is called a direct adjacent sibling selector http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#adjacent-combinators

Comment: thanks, I though this was the best solution and gave me the push to get the end result like it was designed

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a bottom border and for the first also include a top border..

either use an extra class for the first item, or use the `:first-child` pseudo-class (which is not supported on IE6)

Answer (score 0):

As Pekka suggested, prior to deleting his answer, the obvious solution is to amend this style:

```
#tabs .tab div.cont ul li a:hover{color:#fff; background-color:#6fd2c8; border-top:1px solid #7db9b2;  border-bottom:1px solid #7db9b2; height:28px; line-height:28px;}
```

to become:

```
#tabs .tab div.cont ul li a:hover{color:#fff; background-color:#6fd2c8; border-bottom:1px solid #7db9b2; height:28px; line-height:28px;}
```

Not terribly 'adv.', really...Unless we're both missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Remove either the top or bottom border and then set an inline style on the first or last `li` to add the one border that would seem to be "missing."